# iOS Storyboard - Navigation Controller Not Working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitableview

I am having trouble with a Navigation Controller in my iOS project which uses Storyboards.

The main part of the project is a UITabBar.  When the app loads for the very first time the screen RegisterViewController is presented:

[image: Register View Controller]

When the user taps on the "Register" button a HTTP POST request is made, then upon receiving the response (JSON object) the screen QuestionnaireViewController is presented using:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

QuestionnaireViewController *questionnaireViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionnaireView"];
[questionnaireViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[questionnaireViewController setQuestionsAndAnswers:_questionsAndAnswers];

[self presentViewController:questionnaireViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

[image: Questionnaire View Controller]

When the user taps on a cell in QuestionnaireViewController a message is sent to prepareForSegue:sender:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

    AnswersViewController *answersViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSArray *answers = [[_questionsAndAnswers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"answers"];

    [answersViewController setAnswers:answers];
}
```

At this point the app crashes with an error of:
-[AnswersViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Below is a more comprehensive overview of my storyboard, which may help in understanding where I have gone wrong:

[image: Storyboard]

I am stumped as to how to fix this, and am hoping that someone out there is able to help.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: You shouldn't be presenting questionnaireViewController, you should be presenting the navigation controller that it's embedded in. Then in prepareForSegue, you don't need to do anything with a navigation controller, AnswersViewController is the destination view controller.

Comment: rdelmar: I feel a bit stupid now - how do I present the navigation controller that questionnaireViewController is embedded in?

Comment: Just like any other controller, give it an identifier and use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, followed by presentViewControllerAnimated:completion.

Comment: rdelmar: I have tried that, however now the table view in QuestionnaireViewController is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you should present the navigation controller, not its root view controller. Then when you want to populate the root view controller with some data, you need to reference it as the navigation controller's root view controller:

```
UINavigationcontroller *questionnaireNavController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionnaireNavigationController"];
[questionnaireNavController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
QuestionnaireViewController *qvc = (QuestionnaireViewController *)[questionnaireNavController topViewController];
[qvc setQuestionsAndAnswers:_questionsAndAnswers];

[self presentViewController:questionnaireNavController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Second, in prepareForSegue:sender: you don't need to reference a navigation controller at all:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    AnswersViewController *answersVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSArray *answers = [[_questionsAndAnswers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"answers"];

    [answersVC setAnswers:answers];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks rdelmar.  I was almost there first time, however was sending the data to QuestionnaireViewController by using alloc/init.

Your answer is almost 100% correct - I had to get the pointer to qvc by using:
(QuestionnaireViewController *)[[questionnaireNavController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]
as with your solution you get:
"No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'rootViewController'".
Again, many thanks - I can stop pulling out what hair I have left.

Comment: @Nick, Oh right, sorry about that. It should have been [questionnaireNavController topViewController] (but your way works just as well). I've corrected that in my post.

Comment: No need to apologise, you have been a great help. Out of the two ways, would you say that one is a more "correct" way of doing so over the other?

Comment: @Nick, With only one view controller, the two methods are equivalent, but viewControllers[0] will always be the root view controller no matter how many controllers there are, whereas the way I did it gives you the view controller on the top of the stack, which would be the one on screen.

Comment: Sounds like your method is the belt and braces way, and therefore will change my implementation.

Comment: @Nick, "belt and braces"? I don't understand that reference.

Comment: what I mean is that your option appears to be the method that makes sure you get the view controller you want.  I appreciate you say the two methods are equivalent, however your's seems more appropriate (I may be wrong though).

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting the navigationController properly.  Instead of `segue.destinationViewControlle`r, use `self.navigationController`

By calling segue.destinationViewController, you are getting a pointer to the VC you are segueing to (`AnswersViewController`) which doesn't understand the message `viewControllers` because it is not a UINavigationController.

Also the AnswersViewController is objectAtIndex:1 I believe, check this though.

Comment: this for the most part is right but it doesn't seem like he even allocated AnswersViewController so it wouldn't be stored in the viewControllers array of the navigationController, if it's a viewcontroller in the storyboard then he should use [storyBoard instantiateWithIdentifyer:@""]; if it's a tab of the tab view controller then he should do [tabControlelr viewControllerAtIndex:]; that's not the write function but there would be something similar to that

Comment: Dylan, Many thanks for the quick response.  If I change it to self.navigationController I get the error of: "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

Comment: According to your screenshots (the lower one), both QuestionViewController and AnswerViewController are embedded in a UINavigationController.  Confirm that this is so.  If QuestionViewController is NOT in a navigation stack, embed it in one.  (@A'saDickens if AnswersViewController is in the storyboard's navigation stack it should be instantiated from a nib)

Comment: Dylan, QuestionnaireViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController, with QuestionViewController having a push segue off of QuestionnaireViewController.  I have also added a new image giving a more complete overview of my storyboard.

Comment: My suggestion is to use the debugger to step through prepareForSegue and confirm that self.navigationController is not nil, confirm that self is a QuestionnaireViewController, and check that everything is as it should be, if that doesn't work, post on github and I'll check it out.